# Почему "надевать", но "одевайся"?

Tags: глаголы-движения

Если "одевать" другого, а "надевать" на себя, то почему не "надевайся"?

Comment: Потому что ты одеваешь себя, а не надеваешь. Надевать что-то, одевать кого-то

Comment: Related: [“Одену” or “надену”](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11214/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-or-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83)

Comment: The word itself is ok - I can imagine a wizard that commands his clothes to put on himsilf: "Абракадабра! Одежда надевайся!".

Comment: Есть [**надевайся**](https://books.google.com/books?id=R-sGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F%22&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F%22) *.* Этих вопросов будет ещё много, но они перестанут быть трудными, если Вы поймёте систему. У Вас частный случай в этой системе, определяемый приставками `о-` и `на-`, см. объяснение http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9342/is-there-a-vocabulary-list-comparable-to-basic-english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что «надевать» вовсе не означает «надевать на себя», надевать можно на кого угодно и на что угодно:

> Я надел кольцо на палец.
>
> Мы надели на наших девушек карнавальные маски.

Или даже так:

> – Что ты на его голову надел?
>
> ­– Сапог надел.

Разница же в том, что:

> *одевать* мы можем *кого-то*,
>
> *надевать* мы можем *что-то на кого-то* / *на что-то*,

поэтому *одеваться* значит *одевать себя*, а *надеваться* может значить только *надеть себя на кого-то / на что-то*, что, по понятным причинам, в принципе не употребляется, только из-за того, что ситуации, когда человек себя на кого-то надевает крайне редки, мало кому и когда приходится о таком говорить.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что надевать что-то (одежду), а одевать кого-то (человека).
[image]

Поэтому "надевайся" звучит, как указание одежде налезть на тело.

Answer (score 0):

The o-/об-/обо- prefix in Russian means "around". It comes from Proto-Indo-European ***a̯entbhi*** "around", "about", "on the both sides" from the root a̯ent- meaning "end".

So одеваться means thoroughly cloth up, from all sides.

Надевать is to put something on from prefix на- meaning "on". So you can put on a hat or gauntlets but it would not be одеваться because it is not putting clothing around you, from the all sides of your body.